# Higher than 1440p in Gnome Boxes with Spice?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, gnome-boxes

Is it possible to increase the maximum resolution in Gnome Boxes(QEMU KVM) to 4K? Currently it is limited to 1440p. I'm using the Spice drivers.

Host: Ubuntu 15.10 w/ GNOME

Guest: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard